# How to add a printer using a PPD found using lpinfo

Tags: cups, printer, ppd

If I run `lpinfo -m` I get a list of PPD files available on my system:

```
$ lpinfo -m
...
lsb/usr/xerox/xrx7855.ppd Xerox WorkCentre 7855
...
foomatic-db-ppds/Xerox/xrx133.ppd Xerox WorkCentre Pro 133 v3015.103 PS
foomatic:Xerox-WorkCentre_XK35c-lex5700.ppd Xerox WorkCentre XK35c Foomatic/lex5700
```

Of these three examples, I can manually find the path to the PPD of the first two:

```
lsb/usr/xerox/xrx7855.ppd                   -> /usr/share/ppd/xerox/xrx7855.ppd 
foomatic-db-ppds/Xerox/xrx133.ppd           -> /usr/share/foomatic/db/source/PPD/Xerox/xrx133.ppd
foomatic:Xerox-WorkCentre_XK35c-lex5700.ppd -> ???
```

When I want to add a new printer using a specific PPD, I can't use the output of `lpinfo`:

```
$ lpadmin -p foo -P foomatic-db-ppds/Xerox/xrx133.ppd -v 'smb://example.org/foo'
lpadmin: Unable to open PPD "foomatic-db-ppds/Xerox/xrx133.ppd": Unable to open PPD file on line 0.
lpadmin: Unable to open PPD file "foomatic-db-ppds/Xerox/xrx133.ppd" - No such file or directory
```

But using the path works:

```
$ lpadmin -p foo -P /usr/share/foomatic/db/source/PPD/Xerox/xrx133.ppd -v 'smb://example.org/foo'
```

Is there a way to add a printer using a specific PPD by using the output of `lpinfo`?

If not directly, can I translate the output of `lpinfo` to a path and how would I use `foomatic:Xerox-WorkCentre_XK35c-lex5700.ppd`?